# Redis Session State Provider - set operation case sensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, redis, stackexchange.redis

Sometime ago we moved production to use the Redis Cache as ASP.NET Session storage and we noticed very strange behavior in a way that Redis Session provider handles the case of Session keys.

The problem we noticed after migration is following: `Session["test"]` still contains the value after being cleared via `Session.Clear()`, and it was defenitely provider-specific, because failback to `InProc` session storage solved the issue.

At the bottom you can find Redis state, that is the result of the code listed below, and which produces the unexpected behavior on operations with Session, such as `Session.Clear()`, or simple session item retrieval; such state seems to be wrong by definition, because [Session State's keys are case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731283/net-httpsessionstate-case-insensitivity).

**The issue in general:** After little investigation we realized that Redis Session provider will handle Session keys to set data **in case sensitive manner**, unlike Session data retrieval. So it makes possible to create **up to `2^n` different cased keys** for any string (with length n) and they will be stored **separately**, resulting in undefined behavior of its retrieval thought Session object and strange behavior as above in particular.

**How to get there:** Create ASP.NET Web Forms application, add the Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider NuGet package (latest as of now - 1.6.5). Also I'm using Azure Redis instance (PaaS).

The full code of test page is attached.

Here is screencast demonstrating issue: http://screencast.com/t/aCuqqVau.

**The question:** Is this as designed or there is a bug there?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="SessionIssue.Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server" />
<body>
    <script runat=server>
        protected void Step1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Test"] = "Y";
        }

        protected void Step2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["test"] = "X";
        }

        protected void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Clear();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            lbTest.Text = string.Format("{0}", Session["test"]);
        }
    </script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Session["test"]=<asp:Label ID="lbTest" runat="server" />

        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="btStep1" runat="server" Text="Step1" OnClick="Step1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btStep2" runat="server" Text="Step2" OnClick="Step2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="Clear_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Redis state]

Comment: I ran your code but I couldn't find anything wrong, Session["test"] is the same with Session["Test"] and when I called Session.Clear() the values were gone. But I did notice inside Redis the 2 hash sub keys Test and test and it seems at least a performance issue (too many subkeys can be created). The project is now open source on github - try to open an issue there: https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers

Comment: @LiviuCostea,  Session["test"] is the same with Session["Test"] - this is what I also noticed, the Get operation looks correctly case insensitive,  but the Set operation is not. When I set "Test" key - and then, on next request will try to get value using Session["Test"] I will receive value that I previously set using "test" key - that is definitely not expected and doesn't match the InProc provider behavior. I will file a bug as you advised. Thank you!

Comment: @LiviuCostea, I've filed a bug there and added screencast to post, demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/2.2.1. Thanks for reporting the issue.